# Why does report with notitlepage still have a separate title page when there is a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, titles, report

My code:

```latex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In placerat
erat augue, a sodales nunc rhoncus sit amet. Nam aliquam est eros,
vitae efficitur turpis ullamcorper sit amet. Etiam nec libero at lacus
hendrerit tempor vel ut erat. Praesent in urna dictum, congue augue at,
convallis enim. Aliquam at magna ut est sagittis laoreet non sed
tellus. Donec ante erat, rutrum in dapibus sed, fermentum tincidunt
lorem. In et ipsum nibh.

\section{Quisque venenatis}
Quisque venenatis dapibus feugiat. Suspendisse at purus convallis,
imperdiet felis non, pharetra risus. Sed cursus eleifend neque vitae
ornare. Duis rutrum urna in tincidunt scelerisque. Ut tellus mauris,
finibus at tristique nec, volutpat et sem. Nunc euismod justo id semper
faucibus. Aenean maximus ante a sem faucibus molestie sed et tellus.

\end{document}
```

The output PDF shows that a new page has started after the title page. But I thought the `notitlepage` class was meant to prevent a new page from starting after the title page.

Why does a new page start after the title page with this code? What can I do to prevent a new page to be inserted after title page?

Comment: `{\let\chapter\section \tableofcontents}%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `report` the table of contents is set with `\chapter*` and all chapter level headings start a new page in that class. So `\maketitle` is not forcing a page break because of the option but the following chapter does.

You are starting the text with `\section`  rather than `\chapter` which already looks odd in report class, as the numbering is then 0.1, 0.2, ...

Answer (score 0):

`\tableofcontents` command includes a `\clearpage`

So, just `\let` this `\clearpage` command to be an empty command (`\relax`) inside a group before printing the `\tableofcontents`

Check this code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
{\let\clearpage\relax\tableofcontents}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In placerat
erat augue, a sodales nunc rhoncus sit amet. Nam aliquam est eros,
vitae efficitur turpis ullamcorper sit amet. Etiam nec libero at lacus
hendrerit tempor vel ut erat. Praesent in urna dictum, congue augue at,
convallis enim. Aliquam at magna ut est sagittis laoreet non sed
tellus. Donec ante erat, rutrum in dapibus sed, fermentum tincidunt
lorem. In et ipsum nibh.

\clearpage

\section{Quisque venenatis}
Quisque venenatis dapibus feugiat. Suspendisse at purus convallis,
imperdiet felis non, pharetra risus. Sed cursus eleifend neque vitae
ornare. Duis rutrum urna in tincidunt scelerisque. Ut tellus mauris,
finibus at tristique nec, volutpat et sem. Nunc euismod justo id semper
faucibus. Aenean maximus ante a sem faucibus molestie sed et tellus.

\end{document}
```

PS: Take care about @David Carlisle answer too