# Minimal example document to demonstrate the usefulness of notitlepage option

Tags: page-breaking, titles, class-options, clearpage

I am trying to make an example document that would demonstrate the usefulness of `notitlepage` option to beginners of LaTeX. Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\author{Lone Learner}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Dolor Sit}
Amet
\end{document}
```

This fails to demonstrate the usefulness of the `notitlepage` option because chapter heading starts a new section as already discussed in the answer to this question: [Why does report with notitlepage still have a separate title page when there is a table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544459/18587)

Can you suggest a document example I can write that demonstrates the usefulness of `notitlepage`? To be precise, the document example should satisfy both conditions below:

- The LaTeX source example should contain `notitlepage` and the output PDF must not contain a title page. The LaTeX source example must not contain any other LaTeX commands to remove the title page. The `notitlepage` option alone should be sufficient to remove the title page.
- If we remove `notitlepage` from the LaTeX source example and make no other edits, then the output PDF must now contain a title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notitlepage` doesn't remove the titlepage. It only avoids that `\maketitle` creates a page on its own (doesn't use the `titlepage` environment internally):

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\author{Lone Learner}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text on the titlepage


\chapter{Dolor Sit}
Amet
\end{document}
```

[image]